# How to open Facebook Fan Page and check if user liked it

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-webview

Here's the flow I am trying to make work:

1. Activity opens and a Like button is shown to user
2. User clicks on button and Facebook's Login Screen shows up
3. User logins and is directed to Fan Page (via Intent or WebView... or anything else that works :)
4. User likes the page
5. User presses Android's back button and come back to Activity
6. Activity resumes and checks if the user indeed liked the page. If he did, points are given to him.

So, for this solution I am using both RestFB (http://restfb.com/) and Facebook Android API v3.0

When user clicks the Like button, I do the following:

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
            new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    //facebookClient is the RestFB object
            facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(session.getAccessToken());

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FacebookWebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    };
```

With this code I can successfully log into Facebook (get the AUTH_CODE) and then I invoke my WebView, which should direct the user to the Fan Page I want. This WebView activity is very simple and simply do:

```
webView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(FacebookWebViewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/<MyFanPage>");
```

If user presses back button while in the WebView, I should redirect him to my MainActivity. I was expecting the activity's `onResume()` method to trigger when this happens, but it's not, for some reason.... I intend to put the `checkIfLikes(null)` on this method to check if the liked happened or not.

So far, I can check if use liked the page using the following FQL:

```
public void checkIfLikes(View v) {
        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(session.getAccessToken());
                    User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
                    Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("GeoWhere", Page.class);

                    String query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id=" + page.getId() + " and uid=" + user.getId();
                    List<FqlUser> users = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, FqlUser.class);
                } catch(com.restfb.exception.FacebookException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "1" + ex.getMessage());
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "2" + e.getMessage() + e.getStackTrace().toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Can anyone help me achieve this?

And most importantly, I can't find anywhere on the Facebook v3 API for Android a nice way to open the FanPage. Do I really have to use the WebView? I don't like the way the user has to leave my app to Like the fan page... I don't like the UX of this...

Thanks a bunch,
Felipe

EDIT 1:
I am invoking this code now to go to my page:

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {
        try {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/104585606418628"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, ""+e.getMessage());
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/GeoWhere"));
        }
    }
```

It works well and I can like the page. When pressing back button and returning to my Activity, onResume is not invoked. In fact, the whole activity is hanging. Buttons are not answering. When I press back again, onResume is invoked, but then I fail with: `User canceled operation.` and this is happening at `com.facebook.widget.LoginButton`. Very odd.

**EDIT 2**

Seems like I fixed it. Was invoking the startActivity() inside the call() method of Facebook and that was making the call() method not to completely finish. So the state of the Session was not open.
So what I did was:

```
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(session.getAccessToken());

            //startActivity(getOpenFacebookIntent(MainActivity.this));
            //launchFacebook();
            //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FacebookWebViewActivity.class);
            //startActivity(i);

            IS_SOCIAL = true;
        }
```

And somewhere else in the code I check if the user is logged on Facebook and proceed with sending him to the fan page

Take care !!

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can check if someone like a page, you need both user id and the page id.

```
/* make the API call */
new Request(
    session,
    "/{user-id}/likes/{page-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```